# Display real time without update button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to make this page auto update the results of the number in real time. The reason for this, is because the same page is used by 5 different people. Right now, it works fine if they click the UPDATE button first. The button displays current number showing in the database. However I want to eliminate the update button so only the Plus and Minus buttons are needed. To do that, the displayed number has to show any updates in real time.

So I ask, how can I make this happen, so the current number shows without having to click the update button first?

Here is the line of code I am thinking is the issue

```
<input type="number" id="qty" class="count" name="qty2" value="<?php echo  $row["number"];  ?>" >
```

And here is the whole page script

```
<?php
include 'database.php';

    // $sql = "INSERT INTO `number`( `number`) 
    // VALUES ('$qty')";
$sql = "SELECT number FROM number";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body {background:none transparent;
}
</style>


<style type="text/css">
.qty {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
body .qty .bg-dark {
    background-color: #645612a1!important;
}
body{
body {background:none transparent;
}

    }
    .qty .count {
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0 0px;
    min-width: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #00000036;
}
/*.qty .plus {*/
/*    cursor: pointer;*/
/*    display: inline-block;*/
/*    vertical-align: top;*/
/*    color: white;*/
/*    width: 30px;*/
/*    height: 30px;*/
/*    font: 30px/1 Arial,sans-serif;*/
/*    text-align: center;*/
/*    }*/
/*.qty .minus {*/
/*    cursor: pointer;*/
/*    display: inline-block;*/
/*    vertical-align: top;*/
/*    color: white;*/
/*    width: 30px;*/
/*    height: 30px;*/
/*    font: 30px/1 Arial,sans-serif;*/
/*    text-align: center;*/
/*}*/
div {
    text-align: center;
}
/*.minus:hover{*/
/*    background-color: #717fe0 !important;*/
/*}*/
/*.plus:hover{*/
/*    background-color: #717fe0 !important;*/
/*}*/
/*Prevent text selection*/
span{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
input{  
    border: 0;
    width: 2%;
}
nput::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input:disabled{
    background-color:white;
}
#qty{
    
    color:rgb(255, 255, 0);
        font-family: monospace;
}
.top-t{
    
    color:white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
} 
.qty img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div class="qty">
    
  <div class="top-t"> 
    <table width="90%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" bgcolor="#000000">
      <tr> 
        <td> 
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr> 
              <td align="center" valign="middle" width="19%" height="2"><!--<span id="butsaveminus" class="minus bg-dark">-</span>-->Available:</td>
              <td align="center" valign="top" width="9%" height="2"> <?php
    if ($result->num_rows) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 ?> 
                <input type="number" id="qty" class="count" name="qty2" value="<?php echo  $row["number"];  ?>" >
                <?php
    }
}
$conn->close();
?></td>
              <td align="left" valign="top" width="72%" height="2"> 
                <form>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr align="center" valign="middle"> 
                      <td width="98%" align="left" valign="top"><span  id="butsaveminus" class="minus"> 
                        <img  src="minus.png" width="40" height="20"/></span><span  id="butsaveplus" class="plus"><img src="Aadd.png" width="40" height="20"/></span></td>
                      <td width="2%" valign="top" align="left"><span  id="butsaveplus" class="plus"> 
                        <input type="button" value="Update" style="height:30px; width:70px" onClick="history.go(0)" name="button2">
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </div>
                        
  <div></div>
                    </div>


</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.count').prop('disabled', true);
            $(document).on('click','.plus',function(){
                $('.count').val(parseInt($('.count').val()) + 1 );
            });
            $(document).on('click','.minus',function(){
                $('.count').val(parseInt($('.count').val()) - 1 );
                    
                });
        });
</script>
                    



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#butsaveminus').on('click', function() {
        
        $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var qty = $('#qty').val();
        if(qty!=""){
            $.ajax({
                url: "minus.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    qty: qty,
                                
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataResult){
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                    if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                        $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('#fupForm').find('input:text').val('');
                        $("#success").show();
                        $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                    }
                    else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                       alert("Error occured !");
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            alert('Please fill all the field !');
        }
    });
    $('#butsaveplus').on('click', function() {
        
        $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var qty = $('#qty').val();
        if(qty!=""){
            $.ajax({
                url: "save.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    qty: qty,
                                
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataResult){
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                    if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                        $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('#fupForm').find('input:text').val('');
                        $("#success").show();
                        $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                    }
                    else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                       alert("Error occured !");
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            alert('Please fill all the field !');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use  setInterval() with ajax to call "selec number from number" and update id="qty". https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: I would research websockets and server-sent events. Polling with AJAX might not be real-time enough if you have multiple concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

If you need anything updated in real time from the server then you will need an AJAX call to the server.

Have a field with , and then make an interval to make the ajax call to the server every 5 seconds (5000ms), e.g.:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() { 
       $.ajax({url: "/path/to/fetch.php", 
                    success: function(result) {
                $(".myanswer").html(result);
            }});
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

I'm using jQuery for convenience, but you can make a call without.